# Nested Flexbox Breaking Parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to implement a simple nested flexbox function. I'm having an issue where it appears that I can have two levels (vertical columns -> horizontal rows), but if I try to extend beyond that, (vertical -> horizontal -> vertical) it breaks the containers height.

I have a CodePen hosted [here](http://codepen.io/FrederickGeek8/pen/xGoPXd) that better describes my question.
http://codepen.io/FrederickGeek8/pen/xGoPXd

Compiled HTML:

```
<div class="workspace">
  <div class="vertical">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="horizontal">
        <div style="background:pink" class="item"><a>Up</a></div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="vertical">
            <div style="background:red" class="item"><a>Left</a></div>
            <div style="background:orange" class="item"><a>Strange</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background:blue" class="item"><a>Another</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><a>Right</a></div>
    <div style="background:green" class="item"><a>Dang</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Compiled CSS (autoprefixed on CodePen):

```
.workspace {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.vertical > .item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #181a1f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #181a1f;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.horizontal {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.horizontal > .item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #181a1f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #181a1f;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

PS: The platform I will be running the finished product on is a packaged Chromium instance.

Comment: Is it me, or are your `flex-direction` statements backwards? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOqWKp

Comment: Just curious what the expected result is? But it looks like @isherwood nailed it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however the implementation right now is correct. `.vertical` defines a container for columns, but columns are going to be organized in a row. What is on my Codepen looks correct, but if you scroll down you will see that the columns (`.vertical`) break out of their container. http://i.imgur.com/iDcAZlO.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some unnecessary `height: 100%` and the `margin: auto`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLPzR

```
.workspace {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.vertical {
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background:grey;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;

  > {
    .item {
      flex:1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      width:100%;
      border-left: 1px solid #181a1f;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #181a1f;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
} 
.horizontal {
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:grey;
  width:100%;

   > {
    .item {
      flex:1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width:100%;
      border-left: 1px solid #181a1f;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #181a1f;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
}
```